# How to remove these characters from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to load a URL Request, but there are some not desired characters in the URL (I´m retrieving the URL from a remote place, so I can´t change the source).

```
NSString *link = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"link"];
link = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Requesting Link: %@",link); /* see below for output */
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[self.theWebView loadRequest:request];
```

The console shows the NSLog output like this:

```
%0A%09%09%09http://192.168.0...
```

The `loadRequest` doesn't do anything, I´m sure it's because the `NSURL` isn´t encoded properly, but I don´t know how to remove those characters.

### Edit

The Raw string (linebreak and space):

```
Requesting Link: 
        http://192.168.0...
```

Comment: For what it's worth, that's a linefeed and 3 tabs.

Comment: What's the raw string look like?

Comment: Doesn't `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` actually add them in? Whats the link looking like before that?

Comment: @Abizern - Probably the same, only the linefeed and 3 tabs don't (visibly) print (but do create whitespace).

Comment: the NSLog Output of the raw string is without the %0A...signs, but in console the string is printed after a line break and some space, which fits exactly to Hot Licks description.

Comment: If it's always the same, the obvious "fix" is to remove the first 4 raw characters.  If not always the same, lop off chars up to the "http:".  Or use "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are newline and tab characters in your string before the URL. Trim them:

```
NSString *link = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"link"];
link = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to not encode but decode your string, try this:

```
NSString *decoded = [link stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim them before encoding using

```
    link = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

[link stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];